# AWS Customized AMI - Same Volume Id for All Instances Created from that AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, volume, amazon-ami

I created a customized AMI from one of my running instances (windows 7).
The volume Id for instances I create later from that customized AMI is the same for all instances - same as the volume id of the origin instance. I get the volume id by using vol command. For example c:\vol

When I create instances from a public AMI the volume id is different for each.

How can I customize the AMI (creation time or later) or the origin instance from which I customize the AMI in order to get a different volume id for each instance I will launch later from that AMI?

Comment: It's strange if the VolumeIds are the same. It would mean that the same volume is associates with the instances. Which is not right! BTW, C:\Vol is not the volumeId it could be the volume. VolumeId of the Volumes associated with the instances may be seen here : https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=ap-southeast-1#Volumes:

Comment: **`c:\vol`** is **not** what you think it is.